# How can I getText() from EditText in Fragment and pass in Volley Parameters?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-volley

I am using Volley in Fragments for the first time.

Can anyone help me with this. I am trying this following code for the fragment which I am calling from a navigation drawer:

```
public class ChangePassword extends android.app.Fragment implements View.OnClickListener
{
    EditText etOldSignUpPassword;
    EditText etNewSignUpPassword;
    EditText etNewSignUpConfirmPassword;
    ImageButton imageChangePasswordButton;
    ProgressBar pbWeb;
    String old,npass,ncpass;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_change_password, container, false);
    etOldSignUpPassword = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.etOldPassword);
    etNewSignUpPassword = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.etNewSignUpPassword);
    etNewSignUpConfirmPassword = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.etNewSignUpConfirmPassword);
    imageChangePasswordButton = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.imageChangePasswordButton);
    pbWeb = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.pbWebC);
    pbWeb.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    imageChangePasswordButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    return v;
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view.getId() == R.id.imageChangePasswordButton) {

        old = etOldSignUpPassword.getText().toString();
        npass = etNewSignUpPassword.getText().toString();
        ncpass = etNewSignUpConfirmPassword.getText().toString();

        if (!isNetworkAvailable()) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Your Wifi/Data is disabled. Please switch on and try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            pbWeb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            String server_url = "url_working_fine_for_activity_so_no_issue_here";
            StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, server_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if (response.equals("SUCCESS")) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Password Changed Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(loginIntent);
                        pbWeb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        getActivity().finish();
                    } else {
                        pbWeb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Couldn't Change Password. Old Password Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    pbWeb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    map.put("old", old);//etOldPassword.getText().toString() throws NullPointerException
                    map.put("new", npass);//"MY_DEFAULT_VALUE" as value is working fine but that is not the use case
                    map.put("newCon", ncpass);
                    return map;
                }
            };
            //VolleySingleton is fine as working in Activity as well as when I give default values in getParams so no issue in this class 
            VolleySingleton.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).addToReqQueue(strReq);
        }
    }
}
```

**PREV:** *Currently this code leads to a crash.*

**NOTE:** I have tried using onClickListener() directly on imageChangePasswordButton inside onActivityCreated() method without implemeting onClickListener on the class but found on a thread that there is a bug.

**EDIT:** *Current Code as seen is working fine.*

Here is the xml as requested:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".mypackage.ChangePassword">  <!--The class ChangePassword is inside mypackage--> 

<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/pbWebC"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image1"
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_old_email"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/etOldPassword" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_new_password"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/etNewSignUpPassword" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_new_confirm_password"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/etNewSignUpConfirmPassword" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/imageChangePasswordButton"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/reset" />


</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT:** *Code working fine. Thanks for the help. @LongRanger @i-Droid*

Comment: Looking at brackets, It looks like your `onClick` method is outside `ChangePassword` class. does it look like this in your project as well?

Comment: @Sharj nope. Compilation is fine.

Comment: It seems the onclick() event is setup fine. The NullPointerException is mainly because the "etOldPassword" is a null object, which means it might be "R.id.etOldPassword" is not found in your layout(Even the id is not founded in the layout, no exception will be triggered in the app and it will return a null object to the variable). Would you also provide the xml ?

Comment: @LongRanger Hi I have shared the same. The xml looks fine to me. Let me know if you find any mistake. Also let me know if there could be an issue with the context. One more observation. I am using a singleton pattern. When I am clicking on a different fragment,which opens a new activity, the app is producing the expected toast of Password Changed successfully.

Could you check in perspective of Volley if I have overlooked something. Even if I am not using the singleton pattern, I am getting the same behaviour.

Comment: @LongRanger Can you check the additional observation I have shared. The EditText indeed is not being accessed in the fragment. Could you share your comments

Comment: I copied your xml and fragment code in the AS project. I found a compile time error (etSignUpConfirmPassword cannot be resolved ) Where is your id "etSignUpConfirmPassword"

Comment: Post your error log so it would be fine to find the issue rather code and xml

Comment: @LongRanger Was an error. 
Changed etSignUpConfirmPassword to etNewSignUpConfirmPassword. The Crash is resolved, but the Additional observation is still observed as mentioned. Should I call OnDestroyView and set the variables to null?

Comment: @i-Droid Crash issue gone. A rookie mistake. Could you comment on the additional observation. Why this behaviour is observed?

Comment: Sorry I really dun understand what is the question of your additional observation is. Do you want to save the value of edittext in real time instead of capturing it when it called findViewById() method?

Comment: @LongRanger Thanks for pointing out the xml issue. Code is working fine.  Additional behaviour was due to some unhandled exception pointed out via i-Droid. Thanks for your valuable time.